# Specific command in chosen channel only

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

I would like to make a specific command (`!verify`) in the chosen channel.

**Q: What does it mean?**

**A:** The answer is simple. I would like users to be **able to write only this command** to this channel and nothing else.

Library: Discord.js

Comment: use a statement to check if `message.channel.id` is equal to a certain id.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
if (message.channel.id === 'id-of-allowed-channel') {
  //rest of your code
}
```

This way, the command is only executed if the id of the channel where the message is sent in equals the id of the channel that you want the command to work in :)

Answer (score 0):

But I need to be able to write only a certain command in this channel. I already know how to select a specific channel, it's just the command.